# The communication complexity of Hamming distance mod $4$

Tags: communication-complexity

If Alice and Bob each have a bit string of length $n$, what is the randomized communication complexity (either one or two-way) of computing the Hamming distance mod $4$?  It seems this is hard to search for online but I am sure it must be well known.

The one-way  deterministic communication complexity is clearly linear as Bob can learn Alice's entire string from the messages she sends him.  He does this by flipping each bit in his string in turn and seeing if the Hamming distance mod $4$ goes up or down (also mod $4$).

If we change the question to ask for the Hamming distance mod $2$ then Alice need only send $1$ bit to Bob. That is the Hamming weight of her string mod $2$.

Comment: Just a "painted" comment. I have no idea what the answer is, but just out of curiosity I made a 5 lines program to show the $\mod 2$ and $\mod 4$ Hamming distances of $(x,y),\; x,y \in [0..255]$. [$\mod 2$ (black=0, red=1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV8K2.png), and [$\mod 4$ (black=0, red=1, green=2, blue=3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDVJ0.png) ... { "answer_style" : "Wolfram" } :-)

Comment: Are you representing the integers x and y in binary to make them strings?

Comment: @Lembik: yes e.g. x=15, y=5 ->  s1=1111 s2=0101 -> Hamming distance = 2. The resulting images are only doubled in size (512x512) to make them more "enjoyable" :-)

Comment: Your lower bound for the deterministic communication complexity isn't correct. You give a way of learning Alice's input using $n$ instantiations of the Hamming distance protocol. This only shows that the latter needs at least one bit.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Let me check.  In the one-way model Alice sends one message to Bob. Bob can now perform any computation he chooses and for as long as he likes. The first thing he does is flip the first bit in his string. Using the one message Alice sent, he computes the Hamming distance mod $4$ before and after flipping the bit. If it goes up when he flips it (or from $3$ to $0$) then he knows Alice had the same bit as him before flipping.  Otherwise, he knows Alice had the opposite bit. He then moves on to the second bit using *the same* message Alice sent him originally. Why is this not right?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can't decide immediately if the same argument works for two-way deterministic communication so I edited the text in the question.

Comment: I agree that you argument works in the one-way setting, but it's not clear why it should work in the two-way setting (assuming you don't limit the number of rounds).

Comment: Have you tried using the discrepancy method?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No I haven't. I was  assuming that the answer would be well known to an expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following task $f$: Given $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$, Alice and Bob need to determine whether $d(x,y) \bmod{4} \in \{0,1\}$, where $d(x,y)$ is the Hamming distance between $x$ and $y$.

Let $M_f$ denote the matrix corresponding to this problem: $M_f(x,y) = 1$ if the answer is Yes, and $M_f(x,y) = -1$ if the answer is No. The discrepancy method shows that
$$
R_\epsilon(f) \geq \log \frac{1-2\epsilon}{\lambda_{\max}(M_f)/2^n}.
$$
In our case, you can calculate that $\lambda_{\max}(M_f) = 2^{\lceil n/2 \rceil}$ (I checked this for a few $n$ using Krawtchouk polynomials, but presumably there is a simple proof, since all the eigenvalues are nice). For even $n$, this implies that
$$
R_\epsilon(f) \geq \log \frac{1-2\epsilon}{2^{-n/2}} = \frac{n}{2} + \log(1-2\epsilon).
$$

(When $n$ is odd, the lower bound is slightly worse.)

Exactly the same bound is obtained if we replace the condition $d(x,y) \bmod{4} \in \{0,1\}$ with the condition $d(x,y) \bmod{4} \in \{0,3\}$.

Comment: Is this a two-way randomized lower bound and how should think about $\epsilon$ in this lower bound?

Comment: The notation $R_\epsilon(f)$ stands for the minimal amount of bits that need to be communicated by a randomized protocol which is correct on each input with probability at least $1-\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. And just to check, this is for two-way protocols?

Comment: The rule in communication complexity is that protocols are by default two-way. If a protocol is one-way, this will always be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting and I assume the true bound is in fact close to $n$ in this case. Does your method give linear lower bounds for Hamming distance mod $x$ for all $x \geq 3$?  Also, is it easy to explain how the method you have used fails (as it should because there is no linear lower bound) for mod $2$?

Comment: In the mod 2 case the maximal eigenvalue is $2^n$, so you don't get anything. The method seems to work best when you can convert your problem to a balanced function, so in the case of mod 3 you will actually need to work mod 6, which is possible since obtaining the mod 2 is easy.

Comment: Crunching the numbers, the method fails for mod 6: the rank of all matrices I checked seems to be $\Omega(2^n)$.

Comment: Very interesting!